# Rows and columns not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and there are different rows containing 2 columns each.
The problem is that they are not aligning properly.
This is what I want
[image]

and this is what I am getting
[image]

Please tell me what's wrong here.
I have been trying this for more than an hour and somehow it's not working.

Here's the css for this

```
    .container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
}

.first {
  background: rgb(0, 30, 58);
  color: white;
}

.span1,
.span2 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.span1 {
  color: rgb(72, 174, 137);
}

[type="text"] {
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

[type="submit"] {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(72, 174, 137);
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -25px;
}

.use {
  height: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  border: 3px solid rgb(72, 174, 137);
  width: 55%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 210px;
}

.para {
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.para strong {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.second {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 10%;
}

.threebox {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 70px;
}

.col-lg-4 {
  height: 40%;
}

.col-lg-4 > p {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-top-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px;
}

.positions {
  margin-top: 60px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.positions > h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.spanf {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.features {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgb(242, 243, 245);
  height: 1500px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.features .row {

  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.features .row p {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.features button {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.features .row {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.features img {
/*   width: 98%; */
/*   height: 98%; */
  left: 12px;
top: -12px;
box-shadow: -2px 2px 9px;
}

.features .row .col-lg-6 {
/*   padding-right: 15px; */
/*   padding-left: 2px; */
}

.imgright {
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid rgb(72, 174, 137);
  top: 5%;
  width: 40%;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.img2 {
  position: relative;

/*   padding-bottom: 10px; */
}

.imgleft {
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid rgb(72, 174, 137);
  width: 40%;
  top: 5%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

.img3 {
  position: relative;
  left:30px;
/*  top:-20px; */
/*   padding-bottom: 10px; */

}

.pillars {
  background-color: rgb(72, 174, 137);
  height: 350px;
  top: 0;
}
```

Here's the link to the codepen for this - [codepen](http://codepen.io/silentarrowz/pen/KgpQbG)
I have updated the image to show the error properly.
each row has the image and row on different sides
and thus the rows are not aligning properly as shown in the image.

Comment: A **minimal** demo is required, just enough to show the problem...not the whole page.

Comment: Are you referring to the height of the text column and the image column? The images look bigger in your attempt compared to the example.

Comment: It's to do with your .imgleft & .imgright code.
You are setting 40% in these that is effecting the grid.

Comment: if I dont set the width for the image, it stack either above or below the paragraph and that's why I had to set the width.
Anyways, I have updated the post to show the new image and have pointed out the error there. Please take a look.

Comment: You **should not** set a specific width to elements that have width configured using bootstrap values. If you override these values you mess with the grid system and this is what happen. You have 40% width for `.imgright` and 65% for `.features .row` (And these two are only example, you have more...).

Comment: but if I dont set width then it's stacking up one on top of the other.
and I also set width because I wanted to use margin:0 auto; which doesnt work if I dont set the width.
I wanted to center the thing.

Comment: It won't stack if you're using the column classes correctly. Have you looked at the Bootstrap docs? If you have two columns that have the class `col-md-6`, they will appear side by side, and stacked on mobile.

Comment: well, I used col-lg-6 so I dont see a reason for them getting stacked but that's what was happening.
So, do you thinking removing all that styling of col-lg-6 will correct the error??

Comment: using that class means that they will only be side by side when viewed on large desktops, so everything underneath gets stacked. Try changing it to `col-sm-6` or `col-md-6`

Comment: well, okay. I will try that too. But I am viewing this from my laptop which i think is large enough for col-lg-6 to show up properly.

Comment: They stack because you have additional border, padding, etc on your imgright & imgleft. 

Setting the width 40% fixed this issue however throws the grid out.
Try and keep you class="col-lg-6" without additional classes.

If you need to apply classes around the image place a div inside your col-lg-6.

Comment: ok, I get it now. will keep this in mind now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to not change col- divs styles. create other blocks inside them to get what you want. and remember that col- class has paddings.

i would try something like

`<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="text-left">
      <div class="bordered-box">
        <img class="img-responsive img3" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/whizzy/image/upload/v1473309440/graph.jpg" alt="graph">
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <p>EASY TO UNDERSTAND<br><span class="spanf">Optimize Your Product & Category<br> Performance</span><br>
There are plenty of platforms that make it easy to capture data and analytics about your ecommerce site. But when it comes to understanding the data you've captured. It's not always clear what's important and where to make changes.<br>
    <button>Join Now</button></p></div>
</div>`

with style to bordered-box

`.bordered-box{
  display:inline-block;
  border:3px solid #46ab86;;
}`

and here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CRIP/8jjnhwtm/)

Comment: Could you give the question asker an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to show him a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you're using the columns correctly, or else you're styling will just override everything. The idea is that you don't need to use much CSS at all, as it's all in the framework.

Important things are that each row, must have it's own container using `row` as the class. This is what gives it proper structure, and block-ness(!).

Cut down on all your extra styling, as it's not needed. The Bootstrap column classes do this well enough just by themselves.

Below is a pure example of just using Bootstrap to get the rows aligned, and the text set to left or right of the main page.

Example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"><p>Your first row text item, left aligned by default.</p></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="your-image-file.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="dont-forget-your-alt" /></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="your-second-image-file.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="really-dont-forget-your-alt" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right"><p>Your second row text item, wich needs to be right aligned by adding the class to the p tag.</p></div>
</div>
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

do that in css :

```
.right{ float:right; margin-right:10px;}
```

and html :

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 imgleft"> <img class="img-responsive img3" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/whizzy/image/upload/v1473309440/graph.jpg" alt="graph"> </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 right">
            <p>ECOMMERCE FOCUS
                <br><span class="spanf">Decision Focused Dashboards To<br> Supercharge Your Ecommerce Business</span>
                <br> There are plenty of platforms that make it easy to capture data and analytics about your ecommerce site. But when it comes to understanding the data you've captured. It's not always clear what's important and where to make changes.
                <br>
                <button>Join Now</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/24772/